# C++: Defining a variable in a namespace using multiple declarations

Tags: c++, namespaces

For my current project I'm using the Eigen library for matrix algebra. There's a particular vector that I want to define in a namespace called Constants. For Eigen, the preferred constructor for vectors is:

```
Vector3d g; // Initialization
g << 1,2,3; // Values
```

I'm looking for a way to write these to lines when g is a member of a namespace. That is, when it is defined via

```
namespace Constants {
    Eigen::Vector3d g;
}
```

I would like to then call

```
Constants::g << 1,2,3
```

somehow. However, I can't find a way to do this without getting compiler errors.

What is the proper way to do this?

---

What I've tried:

1) Defining g within the scope of the namespace

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"    

namespace Constants {
    Eigen::Vector3d g;
    g << 1,2,3; // <- ERROR: Unknown type name 'g'
}
```

2) Defining g outside the scope of the namespace. (Things in parentheses had no effect)

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"

namespace Constants {
    (extern) Eigen::Vector3d g;
}
(Eigen::Vector3d Constants::g;)
Constants::g << 1,2,3; // <- ERROR: No type name 'g' in namespace 'Constants'
```

3) Defining g with "using namespace" keywords

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"

namespace Constants {
    (extern) Eigen::Vector3d g;
}

using namespace Constants;
g << 1,2,3; // <- 2 ERRORS
            // 1) Expected unqualified-id
            // 2) Unknown type name 'g'
```

Comment: You can't have expressions and statements in namespaces. They have to be within functions.

Comment: You would get the same errors if you didn't use a namespace.

Comment: @Jashaszun I figured as much out. What confuses me is that it seems like you can also store variables in namespaces, but in cases like this there is no way to properly define them.

Comment: @molbdnilo Good to know but you haven't told me why. Please post an answer if you can.

Comment: Because @Jashaszun's comment applies to the file scope as well.

Comment: You can't construct by `Eigen::Vector3d g(1,2,3);` like [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html)?

Comment: Wow... that is incredibly helpful. I missed that special case in the documentation. Thanks for the help!